# Getting the public key exchange

Tags: encryption, pem

To compute the Client Key Exchange message, what method are we meant to use to encrypt the pre master secret with the server`s public key?

```
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
`MII423hasdhashdfxzcvbvwe1209khndasAQWRENWA............
 *lots of extra contents*
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

My PreMaster Secret  in SHA384(#########################) = *random contents*

The client key exchange will be the value of *converted value of random contents of SHA384
using ASN1 decoder or is it the .pem that needs to be converted to get client key exchange?

Comment: Please provide the necessary context for your questions. In this case I guess you're referring to the TLS protocol. If you are quoting text then provide a link to the document, or at least give its title.

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5246#section-7.4.7.1

Comment: For me to solve Client Key Exchange in need to use RSA, using A = g ^ a mod m.  where,   MII423hasdhashdfxzcvbvwe1209khndasAQWRENWA ^ random contents mod m, but I don't know how to get modulo m value of the website